# nodejs async.series post object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a sensortag and a raspberry pi.Raspberry pi collects data from sensortag and tries to send data to google cloud.I use nodejs script for collection.Here is the code:

```js
var util = require('util');

var async = require('async');
var request = require('request');

var SensorTag = require('./index');
var http = require('http');
var CC2650SensorTag = require('./index').CC2650;

var USE_READ = true;
var date = new Date().getTime();
var json_sensor_value_obj = [];
var json_final_obj;

function Sensor_value(type, value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.type = type;
}
function Sensor_object(sensor_value, date) {
    this.sensor_value = sensor_value;
    this.date = date;
}
function send_data(data) {
    console.log("send func. called");
    request({
        url: "http://fasensor.tk/post_data", method: "POST", headers: { "content-type": "application/json" }, json: true, body: JSON.stringify(data)
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        console.log("connection");
        console.log(error);
        console.log(response);
    });
}
    
CC2650SensorTag.discover(function (sensorTag) {
  console.log('discovered: ' + sensorTag);

  sensorTag.on('disconnect', function() {
      console.log('disconnected!');
      send_data(json_final_obj);
    process.exit(0);
  });

  async.series([
      function(callback) {
        console.log('connectAndSetUp');
        sensorTag.connectAndSetUp(callback);
      },
      function(callback) {
        console.log('readDeviceName');
        sensorTag.readDeviceName(function(error, deviceName) {
          console.log('\tdevice name = ' + deviceName);
          callback();
        });
      },
      function(callback) {
        console.log('readSystemId');
        sensorTag.readSystemId(function(error, systemId) {
          console.log('\tsystem id = ' + systemId);
          callback();
        });
      },
      function(callback) {
        console.log('readSerialNumber');
        sensorTag.readSerialNumber(function(error, serialNumber) {
          console.log('\tserial number = ' + serialNumber);
          callback();
        });
      },
      function(callback) {
        console.log('readFirmwareRevision');
        sensorTag.readFirmwareRevision(function(error, firmwareRevision) {
          console.log('\tfirmware revision = ' + firmwareRevision);
          callback();
        });
      },
      function(callback) {
        console.log('readHardwareRevision');
        sensorTag.readHardwareRevision(function(error, hardwareRevision) {
          console.log('\thardware revision = ' + hardwareRevision);
          callback();
        });
      },
      function(callback) {
        console.log('readSoftwareRevision');
        sensorTag.readHardwareRevision(function(error, softwareRevision) {
          console.log('\tsoftware revision = ' + softwareRevision);
          callback();
        });
      },
      function(callback) {
        console.log('readManufacturerName');
        sensorTag.readManufacturerName(function(error, manufacturerName) {
          console.log('\tmanufacturer name = ' + manufacturerName);
          callback();
        });
      },
      function(callback) {
        console.log('enableIrTemperature');
        sensorTag.enableIrTemperature(callback);
      },
      function(callback) {
        setTimeout(callback, 2000);
      },
      function(callback) {
        if (USE_READ) {
          console.log('readIrTemperature');
          sensorTag.readIrTemperature(function(error, objectTemperature, ambientTemperature) {
            console.log('\tobject temperature = %d °C', objectTemperature.toFixed(1));
            console.log('\tambient temperature = %d °C', ambientTemperature.toFixed(1));
            var temp_obj = new Sensor_value('Temperature', ambientTemperature.toFixed(1));
            json_sensor_value_obj.push(temp_obj);

            callback();
          });
        } else {
          sensorTag.on('irTemperatureChange', function(objectTemperature, ambientTemperature) {
            console.log('\tobject temperature = %d °C', objectTemperature.toFixed(1));
            console.log('\tambient temperature = %d °C', ambientTemperature.toFixed(1))
          });

          console.log('setIrTemperaturePeriod');
          sensorTag.setIrTemperaturePeriod(500, function(error) {
            console.log('notifyIrTemperature');
            sensorTag.notifyIrTemperature(function(error) {
              setTimeout(function() {
                console.log('unnotifyIrTemperature');
                sensorTag.unnotifyIrTemperature(callback);
              }, 5000);
            });
          });
        }
      },
      function(callback) {
        console.log('disableIrTemperature');
        sensorTag.disableIrTemperature(callback);
      },
      function(callback) {
        console.log('enableHumidity');
        sensorTag.enableHumidity(callback);
      },
      function(callback) {
        setTimeout(callback, 2000);
      },
      function(callback) {
        if (USE_READ) {
          console.log('readHumidity');
          sensorTag.readHumidity(function(error, temperature, humidity) {
            console.log('\ttemperature = %d °C', temperature.toFixed(1));
            console.log('\thumidity = %d %', humidity.toFixed(1));
            var hum_obj = new Sensor_value('Humidity', humidity.toFixed(1));
            json_sensor_value_obj.push(hum_obj);
            callback();
          });
        } else {
          sensorTag.on('humidityChange', function(temperature, humidity) {
            console.log('\ttemperature = %d °C', temperature.toFixed(1));
            console.log('\thumidity = %d %', humidity.toFixed(1));
          });

          console.log('setHumidityPeriod');
          sensorTag.setHumidityPeriod(500, function(error) {
            console.log('notifyHumidity');
            sensorTag.notifyHumidity(function(error) {
              setTimeout(function() {
                console.log('unnotifyHumidity');
                sensorTag.unnotifyHumidity(callback);
              }, 5000);
            });
          });
        }
      },
      function(callback) {
        console.log('disableHumidity');
        sensorTag.disableHumidity(callback);
      },
      function(callback) {
        console.log('enableBarometricPressure');
        sensorTag.enableBarometricPressure(callback);
      },
      function(callback) {
        setTimeout(callback, 2000);
      },
      function(callback) {
        if (USE_READ) {
          console.log('readBarometricPressure');
          sensorTag.readBarometricPressure(function(error, pressure) {
            console.log('\tpressure = %d mBar', pressure.toFixed(1));
            var air_press_obj = new Sensor_value('Air Pressure', pressure.toFixed(1));
            json_sensor_value_obj.push(air_press_obj);
            callback();
          });
        } else {
          sensorTag.on('barometricPressureChange', function(pressure) {
            console.log('\tpressure = %d mBar', pressure.toFixed(1));
          });

          console.log('setBarometricPressurePeriod');
          sensorTag.setBarometricPressurePeriod(500, function(error) {
            console.log('notifyBarometricPressure');
            sensorTag.notifyBarometricPressure(function(error) {
              setTimeout(function() {
                console.log('unnotifyBarometricPressure');
                sensorTag.unnotifyBarometricPressure(callback);
              }, 5000);
            });
          });
        }
      },
      function(callback) {
        console.log('disableBarometricPressure');
        sensorTag.disableBarometricPressure(callback);
      },
      function(callback) {
          if (sensorTag.type === 'cc2650') {
          async.series([
            function(callback) {
              console.log('readIoData');
              sensorTag.readIoData(function(error, value) {
                console.log('\tdata = ' + value);

                 console.log('writeIoData');
                sensorTag.writeIoData(value, callback);
              });
            },
            function(callback) {
              console.log('readIoConfig');
              sensorTag.readIoConfig(function(error, value) {
                console.log('\tconfig = ' + value);

                 console.log('writeIoConfig');
                sensorTag.writeIoConfig(value, callback);
              });
            },
            function(callback) {
              console.log('enableLuxometer');
              sensorTag.enableLuxometer(callback);
            },
            function(callback) {
              setTimeout(callback, 2000);
            },
            function(callback) {
              if (USE_READ) {
                console.log('readLuxometer');
                sensorTag.readLuxometer(function(error, lux) {
                  console.log('\tlux = %d', lux.toFixed(1));

                  callback();
                });
              } else {
                sensorTag.on('luxometerChange', function(lux) {
                  console.log('\tlux = %d', lux.toFixed(1));
                });

                console.log('setLuxometer');
                sensorTag.setLuxometerPeriod(500, function(error) {
                  console.log('notifyLuxometer');
                  sensorTag.notifyLuxometer(function(error) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                      console.log('unnotifyLuxometer');
                      sensorTag.unnotifyLuxometer(callback);
                    }, 5000);
                  });
                });
              }
            },
            function(callback) {
              console.log('disableLuxometer');
              sensorTag.disableLuxometer(callback);
            },
            function() {
              callback();
            }
          ]);
        } else {
          callback();
        }
      },
      function (callback) {
          console.log('Values are converting to json object...');
          var sensor_obj = new Sensor_object(json_sensor_value_obj, date);
          json_final_obj = JSON.stringify(sensor_obj);
          console.log(json_final_obj);
          console.log('Coverting has finihed.');
        console.log('disconnect');
        sensorTag.disconnect(callback);
      }
    ]
  );
});
```

The important part is end of the async series.I have successfully collected data and make it json format and then disconnect function is called.However, in disconnect function, request is not properly executed because there is no status code output (only "*send func. called*" is printed).
I suspected that the problem is sourced from google cloud but I can post a json object in another nodejs script when it is executed.I **do not know why the request is not working properly in this instance.**

Comment: You should provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: The code requires a hardware (TI sensortag) to begin execution and generate an output.I do not know how I can provide a producible example.Actually, the problem is not directly related to data collection (hardware part) and make it json data.The aforementioned problem is that I can not make a request at the end of the async series.Thanks for your comment by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it's in the following:

```
sensorTag.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('disconnected!');
    send_data(json_final_obj);
    process.exit(0);
});
```

`send_data()` calls the request, which is asynchronous, so `process.exit(0)`, is getting called before you get a response back. Add a callback to `send_data()` and put process.exit() after we get the response back. The following changes will likely fix it:

```
sensorTag.on('disconnect', function() {
  console.log('disconnected!');
  send_data(json_final_obj, () => process.exit(0));
});

function send_data(data, callback) {
    console.log("send func. called");
    request({
        url: "http://fasensor.tk/post_data", method: "POST", headers: { "content-type": "application/json" }, json: true, body: JSON.stringify(data)
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        console.log("connection");
        console.log(error);
        console.log(response);
        callback()
    });
}
```

Comment: when I implemented the solution I get the error :"home/pi/node_modules/noble/lib/peripheral.js:53     callback(null);     TypeError: callback is not a function". I think this problem is related to sensortag disconnect library.It is expected to a function, but I do not know how I can figure it out.By the way, it gives the error after print "disconnected!" and "send func. called".

Comment: I don't know much about sensortag, but maybe it's the arrow function (sensortag might not support arrow functions yet?) Replace `() => process.exit(0)` with `function() {process.exit(0)}` and see if it resolves that error.